# Dot Versus Dollar symbol

Tags: haskell

```
print $ concat ["abc", "bde"]
```

prints

```
abcbde
```

whereas,

```
print . concat ["abc", "bde"]
```

The error thrown in second case is,

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> b0’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
Relevant bindings include
  it :: a -> IO () (bound at <interactive>:3:1)
Possible cause: ‘concat’ is applied to too many arguments
```

`.` (function-composition operator) is used because i thought it will take the output of `concat` function and pass it to the preceding function `print`? What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just precedence, really; this will work fine:

```
(print . concat) ["abc", "bde"]
```

`.` composes two functions to create a new function, whereas `$` is just a way of avoiding parentheses in this context.

Comment: Thank you for a simple explanation for something that I knew how to do via trial and error, yet never really understood why :)

Comment: The difference matters more if you're passing them to higher order functions

Comment: You can also do `print . concat $ ["abc", "bde"]`